# WP_User_Query ignoring 'meta_query' arguments

Tags: ajax, meta-query, wp-user-query

So, I'm trying to do a query on 'members' based on some inputs from a form using AJAX.

The thing is that when searching for a 'role' I get the expected result. But once I try to look for other meta values, the return bring all members in the DB.

I tried in a bunch of ways but I either get the result I just said, or I simply get no result at all (even with the role)

Here is my PHP code that is inside '**functions.php**':

```
function my_ajax_filter_search_callback() {
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    if(isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name'])) {
        $name = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['name'] );
        $searchName = array(
            'search' => $name,
            'search_columns' => array( 'first_name' ),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
        $searchName[] = array(
            'search' => $name,
            'search_columns' => array( 'last_name' ),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
    }

    if(isset($_GET['keywords']) && !empty($_GET['keywords'])) {
        $keywords = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['keywords'] );
        $searchKeywords = array(
            'key' => 'keywords',
            'value' => $keywords,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        );
    }

    if(isset($_GET['countries']) && !empty($_GET['countries'])) {
        $country = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['countries'] );
        $searchCountry = array(
            'key' => 'country',
            'value' => $country,
            'compare' => '='
        );
    }

    if(isset($_GET['disciplines']) && !empty($_GET['disciplines'])) {
        $discipline = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['disciplines'] );
        $searchDiscipline = array(
            'key' => 'disciplines',
            'value' => $discipline,
            'compare' => '='
        );
    }

    if(isset($_GET['roles']) && !empty($_GET['roles'])) {
        $role = sanitize_text_field($_GET['roles']);
    }

    $args = array(
        'role' => $role,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                $searchName
            ),
            $searchKeywords,
            $searchCountry,
            $searchDiscipline
        )
    );


    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    if ( !empty( $user_query->get_results() ) ) {
        $results = array();
        $count = 0;
        foreach ( $user_query->get_results() as $member ) {
            $member_info = get_userdata( $member->ID );
            $results[] = array(
                'id' => $member->ID,
                'name' => $member_info->first_name .' '.$member_info->last_name,
                'role' => $member_info->roles,
                'keywords' => $member_info->keywords,
                'country' => $member_info->country,
                'disciplines' => $member_info->disciplines,
            );

            $count++;
        }

        echo json_encode($results);

    }

    wp_die();
}
```

I even tried creating all the structure for the arguments in the same place to be sure that there is not an extra 'array' or something, same result.

Here is an example of my return when looking for a **name**:
[image]

And here is an example of my return when looking for a **role**:
[image]

The fields I'm trying to search were added with the plugin **Paid Memberships Pro** and that info is located on the '**wp_usermeta**' table. Here is a print of one of those fields '*discipline*':
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But once I try to look for other meta values, the return bring all members in the DB.

Are you sure the meta *other than name* did not work, i.e. all members/users were returned?

Because as I could see it, for your `keywords`, `country` and `disciplines` meta, so long as your `compare` value is good, then the meta query would work and only members having the specified metadata that would be returned.

For example, your `compare` for the `keywords` meta is `LIKE`, so if you searched for `foo` and there were members with `foo` (regardless of the letter case) in their `keywords` meta, then only those members would appear in the user query's results.

So make sure your `compare` value is good, particularly for the `disciplines` meta which I supposed contains multiple values that are separated using a comma (e.g. `discipline 1, discipline 2`) and yet, your `compare` is `=` which means an exact-match search that's commonly used for meta values with a single value.

Now as for the first/last name search, I noticed the following issues:

1. Your meta query clauses are missing `key` (meta key/name) and `value` (meta value), and WordPress ignored the meta query because the meta key is not specified. Also, `search` and `search_columns` are not valid keys for clauses in a meta query.
2. The `array( 'relation' => 'OR', $searchName )` produces `array( 'relation' => 'OR', array( 'search' => ..., ..., ..., array( ... ) ) )` instead of `array( 'relation' => 'OR', array( ... ), array( ... ) )`, so your meta query wouldn't work properly even if you specified the correct meta key.
3. You should use `$searchName[] = array(` to add the `first_name` array, like you did with the `last_name` array.

So, try defining the `$searchName` like this:

```php
$searchName = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
);

$searchName[] = array(
    'key'     => 'first_name', // meta key
    'value'   => $name,        // meta value
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
);

$searchName[] = array(
    'key'     => 'last_name', // meta key
    'value'   => $name,       // meta value
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
);
```

And then in `$args`, add `meta_query` like so:

```php
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    $searchName,
    $searchKeywords,
    $searchCountry,
    $searchDiscipline
)
```

Comment: Man, thanks a lot for your answer. Actually, what was breaking the search apparently was the name part. Once I fixed that, everything is working as expected. I spent 2 days going around in circles trying to figure it out. Much appreciated.